# Javascript - add sum of all costs associated with object key

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, onclicklistener

So I'm trying to count the number of items that the user adds to their cart, as well as print the total cost of all items selected. Counting the number of items works properly, but I'm struggling to figure out how to access the specific cost associated with each item the user chooses to select and take the sum of all of those items together, representing the variable `totalCost`.

For example, if the user clicks <kbd>Add</kbd> next to the iMac as well as <kbd>Add</kbd> next to the Windows PC, the total cost should be 2000 + 1300 = 3300. In the `calculate()` function, I attempted to iterate through all the items under the electronics department and check if the user clicked a button next to a certain item but it messed up my program which is why I commented the function out. Similar to the count variable, I'm trying to successfully get the total cost to update every time the user chooses to add something to their cart. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```js
let count = 0;
let totalCost = 0;

function init() {
  count = 0;
  let button = document.getElementById("but");
  button.onclick = buttonClicked;
}

function buttonClicked() {
  count++;
  let div = document.getElementById("coutner");
  div.innerHTML = "You have " + count + " items and a total cost of $" + totalCost;
}

function showOptions(el) {
  let userPicked = el.value;
  var div = document.getElementById("div");
  if (userPicked != 'none') {
    var newContent = (electronics.store);
    newContent += '<div>';
    Object.keys(electronics.inventory).forEach(key => {
      newContent += key;
      newContent += '<div>';
      var items = Object.values(electronics.inventory[key]);
      items.forEach(item => {
        newContent += '<div>';
        newContent += `&nbsp; <span class="brand"> ${item.brand} </span>  <span class="price">$${item.cost}</span>`;
        newContent += `<input type=button value="Add" onclick="add(this)"/>`
        newContent += '</div>';
      });
      newContent += '</div>';
    });
    newContent += '</div>';
    div.innerHTML = newContent;
  }
}

function add(add) {
  console.clear();
  console.log(add.closest('div').textContent.trim());
  buttonClicked();
}


let electronics = {
  store: "Mike's Computers",
  inventory: {
    "Laptops": {
      0: {
        brand: "iMac",
        cost: 2000
      },
      1: {
        brand: "Dell",
        cost: 600
      }
    },
    "Computers": {
      2: {
        brand: "Windows PC",
        cost: 1300
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
</div><br />
<div class="dropdown">
  <form>
    <select name="list" id="list" accesskey="target" onchange="showOptions(this); buttonClicked(this)">
      <option value="none">Select a restaurant</option>
      <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
    </select>
    <input type=button id="but" value="Select" onclick="showOptions(); buttonClicked()" />
    <div><mark id="coutner"></mark></div>
  </form>

</div>
<div id="div"></div>
```

I kept getting a formatting error when trying to show my comment so here it is separately (it was in the js file below `init()`)

```
/*
function calculate(){
    if(userPicked == 'Electronics'){
        Object.keys(electronics.menu).forEach(key => {
             var items = Object.values(electronics.menu[key]);
               items.forEach(item => {
                  if(buttonClicked(){
                      totalCost += item.cost;
                  }
             });
        }); 
    }
}
*/
```

Comment: you could store the identifier in a data-id attribute on the button and on click retrieve the according object by the identifier, but rather i would just store the selected products in a seperate array. Also i guess it would be better for you to use real arrays of objects in object properties instead of key 0,1,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your code by passing the item cost in to the `add()` function.

Also I have renamed your function `buttonClicked` to what it actually does - updating the display.

Always try to keep your functions clean and only have them do one thing at a time. By moving the `count++` from the update function into the place where it actually belongs - the `add` function - you separate functionality and also fix your off-by-one error in the display.

```js
let count = 0;
let totalCost = 0;
let div = document.getElementById("coutner");

function init() {
  count = 0;
  let button = document.getElementById("but");
  button.onclick = updateDisplay;
}

function updateDisplay() {
  div.innerHTML = `You have ${count} items and a total cost of $${totalCost}`;
}

function showOptions(el) {
  let userPicked = el.value;
  var div = document.getElementById("div");
  if (userPicked != 'none') {
    var newContent = (electronics.store);
    newContent += '<div>';
    Object.keys(electronics.inventory).forEach(key => {
      newContent += key;
      newContent += '<div>';
      var items = Object.values(electronics.inventory[key]);
      items.forEach(item => {
        newContent += `
<div>&nbsp;
  <span class="brand"> ${item.brand}</span>
  <span class="price">$${item.cost}</span>
  <input type=button value="Add" onclick="add(this,${item.cost})"/>
</div>`;
      });
      newContent += '</div>';
    });
    newContent += '</div>';
    div.innerHTML = newContent;
  }
}

function add(element,cost) {
  console.clear();
  totalCost += parseInt(cost);
  count++;
  console.log(element.closest('div').textContent.trim());
  updateDisplay();
}


let electronics = {
  store: "Mike's Computers",
  inventory: {
    "Laptops": {
      0: {
        brand: "iMac",
        cost: 2000
      },
      1: {
        brand: "Dell",
        cost: 600
      }
    },
    "Computers": {
      2: {
        brand: "Windows PC",
        cost: 1300
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
</div><br />
<div class="dropdown">
  <form>
    <select name="list" id="list" accesskey="target" onchange="showOptions(this); updateDisplay(this)">
      <option value="none">Select a restaurant</option>
      <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
    </select>
    <input type=button id="but" value="Select" onclick="showOptions(); updateDisplay()" />
    <div><mark id="coutner"></mark></div>
  </form>

</div>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: The code works, but I'm not giving an upvote because there is no explanation to it - which is essential for learning.

Comment: NP it's upto you. I'm just writing it